# Semantically passive verbs

Tags: terminology

Certain (syntactico-morphologically) active verbs signify a passion rather than an action.  For example, *to fall,* signifies something that can hardly be called an action.  It belongs to its concept that one cannot do it on purpose.  One might perhaps call such verbs *semantically passive.*  Or is there already a term for them?

Comment: *Unaccusative*?

Comment: @rchivers, that looks right; thanks!  though i remain unconvinced of the felicity of the term.

Comment: It may not be the most felicitous of terms, but unaccusative (and unergative) verbs is a traditional and commonly used term for them.

Comment: Not really traditional, except inside a rather small circle. It's a metaphor of ergativity, which actually exists in some languages. But only some linguists feel qualified to deal with the absence of ergativity.